# Plotting Multiple Graphs using R

Tags: r, graph

I currently have a dataset which has a format of: (x, y, type)

I've used the code that is found on the example [of plotting with Postgres through R.](http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/Tidbits/bernier/art_66/graphingWithR.html)

My question is: How would I get R to generate multiple graphs for each unique "type" column?

I'm new to R, so my appologies if this is something that is extremely easy and I just lack the understanding of loops with R.

So lets say we have this data:

```
(1,1,T), (1,2,T), (1,3,T), (1,4,T), (1,5,T), (1,6,T), 
(1,1,A), (1,2,B), (1,3,B), (1,4,B), (1,5,A), (1,6,A), 
(1,1,B), (1,2,B), (1,3,C), (1,4,C), (1,5,C), (1,6,C),
```

It would plot 4 individual graphs on the page. One for each of the types T, A, B, and C. [Ploting x,y]

How would I do that with R when the data coming in may look like the data above?

Comment: Try providing a small [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/324364) example with data, and some specific descriptions of the graphs you're looking to make. "multiple graphs" is pretty vague.

Comment: See items (4) and (9) at this link: http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/

Comment: Does your data look like: `test <- data.frame(x=rep(1,18),y=rep(1:6,3),type=c("T","T","T","T","T","T","A","B","B","B","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C"))`?

Comment: It comes from PL/R [postgres] but the previous edits people claimed that had no relation to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the other post has some good info, there's a faster way to do all that. So assuming your data frame or matrix is called `DF` and is in the form above (where each `(1,2,B)` or whatever is a row), then:

```
by(DF, DF[,3], function(x) plot(x[,1], x[,2], main=unique(x[,3])))
```

And that's it.

If you'd like all the four plots to be on the same page, you can first change the graphing `par`amter option:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
```

And back to default `par(mfrow=c(1,1)` when you're done.

Comment: It might be safer to do `by(DF, DF$type, function(x) plot(x$x,x$y))` as using the indexing like `x[1,]` gives a different result to @DrewSteen's ggplot answer for me. Which I think has to do with the `[` returning a slice of the data.frame instead of a vector. It would also prevent any issues regarding the order of the variables - say if y came before x.

Comment: Yeah, that's my preference too. He didn't give `colNames` and I thought it may have been a matrix, but `$` is the better option =).

Comment: Theres way more than 4 graphs. The name of each graph would be the type.

Comment: You're right! I had the comma in the wrong place for `x[1,]`, it should be `x[,1]` (editted). To name each graph after the type, put `main=unique(x$type)` or `main=unique(x[,3])` in the `plot` argument.

Answer (score 4):

I'm quite fond of the `ggplot2` package, which does the same thing that user1717913 suggests, but with slightly different syntax (it does a lot of other things very nicely, which is why I like it.)

```
test <- data.frame(x=rep(1,18),y=rep(1:6,3),type=c("T","T","T","T","T","T","A","B","B","B","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C"))

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(test, aes(x=x, y=y)) + #define the data that the plot will use, and which variables go where
  geom_point() + #plot it with points
  facet_wrap(~type) #facet it by the type variable
```

[image]

Comment: It looks nice but how can you ensure that it only does 4 graphs per page?

Comment: It will automatically make as many panels as there are unique values of the facetting variable (here, `type`). If you want to plot fewer panels than that, you can feed ggplot a subset of the data: `ggplot(subset(test, type=="A" | type=="B")...` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

`R` is really cool in that there's a bazillion (that's a technical term) different ways to do most things. The way I would do is is to split the data along the groups, and then plot by group.
To do that, the `split` command is what you want (I'll assume your data is in an object called `data`):

```
data.splitted <- split(data, data$type)
```

Now the data will have this form (let's assume you have 3 types, A, B, and C):

```
data.splitted  
 L A
 | L x y type
 |   1 4  A
 |   3 6  A
 L B
 | L x y type
 |   3 3  B
 |   2 1  B
 L C
   L x y type
     4 5  C
     5 2  C
```

and so on. You would reference the "4" in the y column of group A like so:

`data.splitted$A$y[1]` or `data.splitted[[1]][[2]][1]` Hopefully seeing them both together makes enough sense.

Now that we have the data split, we're getting closer.
We still need to tell `R` that we want to plot a bunch of graphs to the same window. Now, this is just one way to go about it. You could also tell it to write each graph to a image file, or a pdf, or whatever you want.
`groups <- names(data.splitted)` puts your different types into a variable for reference later.

```
par(mfcol=c(length(groups),1))
```

Using mfcol fills the graphs in vertically. the mfrow option fills in horizontally. The `c()` just combines input. The `length(groups)` returns the total number of groups.
Now we can work on the for-loop.

```
for(i in 1:length(data.splitted)){   #  This tells it what i is iterating from and to.
                                     #    It can start and stop wherever, or be a 
                                     #    sequence, ascending or descending,
                                     #    the sky is the limit.
tempx <- data.splitted[[i]][[x]]     #  This just saves us
tempy <- data.splitted[[i]][[y]]     #    a bunch of typing.
plot(tempx, tempy, main=groups[i])   #  Plot it and make the title the type.
rm(tempx, tempy)                     #  Remove our temporary variables for the next run through.    
}
```

So you see, it's not too bad when you break it down into its components. You can do pretty much anything this way. I have a project I'm working on right now, where I'm doing this for 18 lidar metrics that I calculated using *another* for loop.
Commands to read up on:

```
split, plot, data.frame, "[", 
par(mfrow=___) and par(mfcol=___)
```

[Here's](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/layout.html) a [few](http://gallery.r-enthusiasts.com/) helpful [links](http://www.personality-project.org/R/r.commands.html)  to get you started. The most helpful one of all is built right in to `R` though. a `?` followed by a command will bring up the html help for that command in your browser.
Good luck!

Comment: This assumes your data coming in is just a 3 column matrix. You may have to do some manipulation to get it into that form.

Comment: It is a 3 column matrix. The reason I asked what I did is that [from my experience with Matlab] that using a loop is not the quickest way of goign about it... they tend to have things just for that